# button is not clickable in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi i want to try to automate click speed test using selenium but having some errors
Main problem is that the button can be clicked but is not clickable in while loop.

my code is this

```
import selenium
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
import contextlib as textmanager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

from urllib3.packages.six import b
PATH= "C:\chromedrivers\chromedriver.exe"
driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)


list_of_words=[]


driver.get("https://clickspeedtest.com/")

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ez-accept-all']").click()

button= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='clicker']").click()

k=0

time.sleep(0.5)
while k != 100:
    button.click()
    k=k+1
```

the error i am getting is this dont know why

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ramhelsinki\projects\click_text.py", line 36, in <module>
    button.click()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'
```

this is the source code of the button or the click area

```
<button id="clicker" type="button" class="rbutton" style="width: 100%; height: 250px; display: none;">Click Here to start playing</button>
```

Comment: Hi! `.click()` method return `None`, in this line: `button= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='clicker']").click()` so because of that `button` has `None` value, and when you're trying to execute `.click()` next time on `None` it throws an error. As a workaround use `button= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='clicker']")` and on the next line `button.click()`.

Comment: `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)` might be even faster and more stable.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because button tag is not found. try doing this

```
 button= driver.find_element_by_ID('clicker')
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the button is changing after the first click.
Try this:

```
button= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='clicker']")

while button.is_displayed():
    button.click()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    button= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='clicker']")
    k=k+1
```

Also pay attention that after 5 seconds the game is over and you will not be able to click the button again.
You have to validate if the button is displayed before clicking on it as I suggested here.

Comment: what if not sleep?

Comment: Need to debug. Not sure it will work correctly. Need to see the site response limit. However I guess the sleep can be shortened.